# How do I permanently disable a specific display in gdm?

Tags: nvidia, display-manager, bumblebee

My laptop has an unknown display always active in the background. It is called "unknown display" in the system settings on Ubuntu GNOME, and it was the same when I was using Unity. I have once installed Enlightenment before, and I also had to explicitly switch off that display in the settings. This was no problem for me since I only need to switch them off once.

Now that I'm using Ubuntu GNOME, gdm seems to behave as if there is another display to the right, beyond the built-in display. I can easily switch it off by using Ctrl+P, but this solution is only temporary. This problem currently causes some rendering faults whenever I move my mouse before logging in, and it causes the background image to be misplaced to the right as the display manager tries to find the center of the two displays.

My laptop has a VGA port and an HDMI port. I have once tried connecting my laptop to a TV through HDMI, and the result was that the "Unknown Display" disappeared and was replaced by "HDMI *something*".

I would like to permanently disable the "Unknown Display" in gdm. How can I do that?

**Update:**

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-2 disconnected
VGA-1-2 connected
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI-1-2 disconnected
  1024x768 (0x45)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x46)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x47)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

Update:
Output of `lshw -C video`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108M [GeForce 610M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:a3000000-a307ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:a3400000-a37fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Would you please post your Graphics Driver Information?

Comment: I think you mean monitor, not display (these are X11 technical words, but I think I know what you mean). Can you open a terminal and type `xrandr`, then post the output in your question.

Comment: @eyoung100 Where can I get that information? Afaik, lspci says I have an Intel 2nd Generation Integrated Graphics, and I also have an NVIDIA GeForce 610M on nouveau.

Comment: Are you using the [Bumblebee Driver for Optimus](http://bumblebee-project.org/)?  Also there is the [Ironhide Fork](https://github.com/MrMEEE/ironhide).  When using this type you should only use intel to drive and remove nouveau, and then use `optirun` to enable/disable the Nvidia card on the fly, saving you battery.  The "unknown display" is coming from the nouveau driver, which should be off.

Comment: @eyoung100 No, all my drivers are provided by Ubuntu GNOME, no PPA or other external sources at all.

Comment: Please read the[Ubuntu Bumblebee Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee), and then issue `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic && reboot` after enabling the `multiverse` and `universe` repositories.  This has nothing to do with gnome, I'll be retagging shortly.

Comment: Also please post the output of `lshw -C video` and welcome to U&L.

Comment: @eyoung100 the output has now been posted. The output is after I have run the command you have given above, but I removed the reboot because I was reading something. I am rebooting now.

Answer (score 2):

> Whew! its 5 years since this has been posted that's a long time. I don't know if it may be of relevance to you today. But anyway for the sake of https://unix.stack-exchange.com I'm posting the reply so that this question does not remain unanswered.

I had this issue with my dual integrated graphics, so after some ddgs I found the solution:

- Edit your grub file: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-2:d`
- Execute `sudo update-grub` and then reboot.

Many similar questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/398903/unknown-display-besides-laptop-built-in-display-old-question-but-with-no-answer
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/381787/xrandr-always-has-a-vga-1-or-vga-2-without-physical-display
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/283018/ubuntu-detects-2-monitors-when-i-only-have-one
- [Unknown display causing elongated screenshot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560743/unknown-display-causing-elongated-screenshot)