# Unknown display causing elongated screenshot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, graphics, xrandr

I'm facing some problems with the display. I had this previously but I cannot exactly remember how I solved it then... Okay here is the thing:
[Login Screen - Misbehaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYiz.jpg)

[image: screen]
What have I tired, didn't work this time:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/398903/unknown-display-besides-laptop-built-in-display-old-question-but-with-no-answer
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/283018/ubuntu-detects-2-monitors-when-i-only-have-one

> Look in `/sys/class/drm` for a list of your computers outputs.Mine was labelled as "card0-VGA-1". Just remove the "card0-" and that's the name of the output in question.

What does it mean... rename the file...? or remove files beginning with such name...?

#### Some important outputs:

**`$ lspci | grep -i vga`**

```bsh
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
```

**`$ ls /sys/class/drm`**

```bsh
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-LVDS-1  card0-VGA-1  card1  card1-HDMI-A-2  card1-VGA-2  renderD128  renderD129  version
```

**`$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'`**

```bsh
VGA-0
LVDS-1-1
```

**`$ xrandr -q`**

```bsh
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1600x900      59.82  
   1400x900      59.88  
...
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.64*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
...
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1360x768 (0x47) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80H
```

**`$ cat /etc/default/grub`**

```bsh
...
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"
...
```

Here is my *primary* graphic driver info:
[image: driver]

#### What works temporarly...

- Mirroring the display is the current workaround. But it still affects the login screen if I log-out (not lock-out)
- `xrandr --auto && xrandr --output VGA-0 --off` also works but is not a permanent solution

#### Something related...?

I'm getting these messages repeatedly in tty1:

```bsh
...
[    342.959335] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000000 Count 00000ffc
[    351.146800] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000000 Count 00000ffd
[    359.334410] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 16, Head 00000000 Count 00000ffe
...
```

The GPU temperature is shooting upto 65°C. Should I be concerned? 
 Here's my system info:

```bsh
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee            joe@eOS 
      eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee         ------- 
    eeeee  eeeeeeeeeeee   eeeee       OS: elementary OS 5.1 Hera x86_64 
  eeee   eeeee       eee     eeee     Host: Dell System XPS L502X 
 eeee   eeee          eee     eeee    Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic 
eee    eee            eee       eee   Uptime: 34 mins 
eee   eee            eee        eee   Packages: 2369 
ee    eee           eeee       eeee   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
ee    eee         eeeee      eeeeee   Resolution: 1360x768 
ee    eee       eeeee      eeeee ee   DE: Pantheon 
eee   eeee   eeeeee      eeeee  eee   WM: Mutter(Gala) 
eee    eeeeeeeeee     eeeeee    eee   Terminal: io.elementary.t 
 eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    eeeee    CPU: Intel i5-2410M (4) @ 2.900GHz 
  eeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeee      eeee     GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M 
    eeeee                 eeeee       GPU: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family 
      eeeeeee         eeeeeee         Memory: 2448MiB / 11899MiB 
         eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

Can anyone help me with this? How did `VGA-0` appear? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely reinstalled the elementary OS. Then straight away installed the Ubuntu drivers with

```bsh
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

It installed the most accurate NVIDIA drivers and then till now I've not faced this issue so far.